# How to handle dynamic optional list with with map

Tags: java, arrays, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I do have a spring boot project developed using web-flux which interacts with Dataverse APIs to fetch the details which works fine if dataverse do have the matching records based on the Odata query but returns an exception when it does not have any records in response. Below is the methods for the same.

```
 @Override
    public Mono<ClientEntity> findPositionWorkerAssignmentByJobPositionId(UUID jobPositionId) {

        ODataEntitySetRequest<ClientEntitySet> request = microsoftOData4Client.getRetrieveRequestFactory()
                .getEntitySetRequest(microsoftOData4Client.newURIBuilder(microsoftOData4Client.getServiceRoot())
                                             .appendEntitySetSegment(positionWorkerAssignmentMapEDMEntitySet.getName())
                                             .expand("cdm_WorkerId", "cdm_JobPositionId")
                                             .filter(String.format(
                                                     "_cdm_jobpositionid_value eq %s and cdm_WorkerId/cdm_workerid ne" +
                                                     " null" +
                                                     " and cdm_JobPositionId/cdm_jobpositionid ne null",
                                                     jobPositionId))
                                             .top(1).build());

        request.setPrefer("odata.include-annotations=OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue");
        Mono<ODataRetrieveResponse<ClientEntitySet>> blockingRequestWrapper = Mono.fromCallable(request::execute);

        return blockingRequestWrapper.subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
                .map(blockingResponse -> {
                    if (blockingResponse.getBody() != null && !blockingResponse.getBody().getEntities().isEmpty()) {
                        return blockingResponse.getBody().getEntities().get(0);
                    } else {          
                        return null;
                    }
                }).onErrorStop();
    }
```

If I do not use if condition to check and directly access `blockingResponse.getBody().getEntities().get(0)` it results in Index 0 out of bounds for length 0 as it's an empty list and if I do return null in else condition I am getting The mapper returned a null value. How can I fix the issue?

```
if (blockingResponse.getBody() != null && !blockingResponse.getBody().getEntities().isEmpty()) {
       return blockingResponse.getBody().getEntities().get(0);
} else {          
       return null;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using ```Optional```

Comment: Hello @Arpit, I have tried `return blockingRequestWrapper.subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
            .map(blockingResponse -> Optional.of(blockingResponse.getBody().getEntities().get(0)).orElse(null)).onErrorStop();` but it results in Index 0 out of bounds for length 0

Comment: ```List someList = blockingResponse.getBody().getEntities();
Optional.of(CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(someList)) ? someList.get(0) : null);```

Comment: @Arpit unfortunately,  I am getting the same message

Comment: What about `blockingResponse.getBody().getEntities().stream().findFirst().orElse(null);` ? `findFirst()` returns an `Optional`, if it is empty (in case of empty list), `orElse` provides a default value

Comment: Use `mapNotNull` operator instead of `map`